# My margin notes are not on the same line as my text

Tags: marginpar

In the following MWE, we can see that the notes in the margin are shifted downwards.
If a few letters are removed, the margin is properly aligned with the text.

I prefer to use \myrightmargin instead of modifying the \marginpar command.
I use \reversemarginpar (is it optimal ?) for I use the twoside option of the class article and for I want the notes to be always on the right !

How to glue the margin notes to the same line of the text ?

```
   \documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}

\newcommand{\myrightmargin}[1]{
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{
{#1}
}
}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\section{first section}
    $
j=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
$
\marginpar{
%\hspace*{-1.1\marginparsep}
the margin
}

\lipsum[1-8]
random text to get closer to the right margin;random text to get closer too.
\marginpar{
%\hspace*{-1.1\marginparsep}
the margin
}


random text to get closer to the right margin;random text to get closer too.
\myrightmargin{my second margin}



\end{document}
```

Well my first margin note with $..$ is on the left; I do not see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You introduced a lot of white space from ends of lines, both in the document before your marginpar commands and within the command definition.

```
 \documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}

\newcommand{\myrightmargin}[1]{%
%\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{%
#1%
}%
}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\section{first section}
\reversemarginpar

\lipsum[1-8]
random text to get closer to the right margin;random text to get closer too.%
\marginpar{%
%\hspace*{-1.1\marginparsep}
the margin%
}


random text to get closer to the right margin;random text to get closer too.%
\myrightmargin{my second margin}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed ! So is possible to put \myrightmargin{my second margin} on a newline and still not introducing the spaces ?

Comment: I place \removelastskip just before \marginpar{...} in my command. It seems to work.

Comment: @Phillip You can use a `%` as in my edit. Remember TeX is primarily optimised for _text_ and a newline is treated as a space and spaces are not ignored: they typeset spaces between words. I think it is much clearer and robust to not add a space rather than explicitly add a space and then remove it.

Comment: After some tests, \unskip and \removelastskip do work but not for lists ! I have a configuration where there is a display \[ \] in the last item of a list and the list itself reaches the bottom of the page. In this case, the margin note goes to the next page !